# css3 media query in header not working

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have two style sheets, one for mobile, one for computers.
I want to use my mobile sheet by default.

my header checks:

```
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='all' href='css/mobile.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 580px)' href='css/large.css' />
```

but I still seem to be using my large stylesheet when I check on a mobile browser! (iphone 4)

Comment: Why exactly do you say that? What is the behavior? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 0):

try to do something like this:
(code of mine)

```
<link href="css/mobile_portrait.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)">
<link href="css/mobile_landscape.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (orientation: landscape)">
<link href="css/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 769px)">
<link href="css/netbook.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1024px)">
<link href="css/desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1224px)">
```

(it's only and example)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that iphones seem to resize content.

I used :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

...to prevent re-sizing in the phones browser.

Put this tag in the head, right before my media queries.
Now the media query functions properly.